# Difference Between Python's Functions `cls.score` and `cls.cv_result_`

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I have written a code for a logistic regression in Python (Anaconda 3.5.2 with sklearn 0.18.2). I have implemented `GridSearchCV()` and `train_test_split()` to sort parameters and split the input data.

My goal is to find the overall (average) accuracy over the 10 folds with a standard error on the test data. Additionally, I try to predict *correctly predicted class labels*, creating a *confusion matrix* and preparing a *classification report* summary.

---

Please, advise me in the following:

(1) Is my code correct? Please, check each part.

(2) I have tried two different *Sklearn* functions, `clf.score()` and `clf.cv_results_`. I see that they give different results. Which one is correct? (However, the summaries are not included).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Load any n x m data and label column. No missing or NaN values.
# I am skipping loading data part. One can load any data to test below code.

sc = StandardScaler()
lr = LogisticRegression()
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('sc', sc), ('lr', lr)])
parameters = {'lr__C': [0.001, 0.01]}

if __name__ == '__main__':

        clf = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=10, refit=True)

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Data, labels, random_state=0)


       # Train the classifier on data1's feature and target data
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

        print("Accuracy on training set: {:.2f}% \n".format((clf.score(X_train, y_train))*100))
        print("Accuracy on test set: {:.2f}%\n".format((clf.score(X_test, y_test))*100))
        print("Best Parameters: ")
        print(clf.best_params_)

     # Alternately using cv_results_
       print("Accuracy on training set: {:.2f}% \n", (clf.cv_results_['mean_train_score'])*100))
       print("Accuracy on test set: {:.2f}%\n", (clf.cv_results_['mean_test_score'])*100))

    # Predict class labels
    y_pred = clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)

    # Confusion Matrix
    class_names = ['Positive', 'Negative']
    confMatrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    print(confMatrix)

    # Accuracy Report
    classificationReport = classification_report(labels, y_pred, target_names=class_names)
    print(classificationReport)
```

I will appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

- First of all, the desired metrics, i. e. the *accuracy* metrics, is already considered a default scorer of `LogisticRegression()`. Thus, we may omit to define `scoring='accuracy'` parameter of `GridSearchCV()`.
- Secondly, the parameter `score(X, y)` returns the value of the chosen metrics **IF** the classifier has been refit with the `best_estimator_` after sorting all possible options taken from `param_grid`. It works like so as you have provided `refit=True`. Note that `clf.score(X, y) == clf.best_estimator_.score(X, y)`. Thus, it does not print out the averaged metrics but rather the best metrics.
- Thirdly, the parameter `cv_results_` is a much broader summary as it includes the results of each fit. However, it prints out the **averaged** results obtained by averaging the batch results. These are the values that you wish to store.

---

#### Quick Example

Let me hereby introduce a toy example for better understanding:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 0.2)    

param_grid = {'C': [0.001, 0.01]}
clf = GridSearchCV(cv=10, estimator=LogisticRegression(), refit=True, 
param_grid=param_grid)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.best_estimator_.score(X_train, y_train)
print('____')
clf.cv_results_
```

This code yields the following:

> 0.98107957707289928  # which is the best possible accuracy score
>
> ---
>
> {'mean_fit_time': array([ 0.15465896,  0.23701136]),
>
> 'mean_score_time': array([ 0.0006465 ,  0.00065773]),
>
> 'mean_test_score': array([ 0.934335 ,  0.9376739]),
>
> 'mean_train_score': array([ 0.96475625,  0.98225632]),
>
> 'param_C': masked_array(data = [0.001 0.01],
>
> 'params': ({'C': 0.001}, {'C': 0.01})

`mean_train_score` has two mean values as I grid over two options for `C` parameter.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, though, my question is specific to understand the difference between `clf.score()` and `clf.cv_results_`. Besides, I am using `train_test_split()` for generating **train** and **test** data. While in your example you use the whole data **X** and labels **y**. Can you please show an example with my code above? In particular, I want to understand that how `score(X_train, y_train)` and `score(X_test, y_test)` is different from `cv_results` for the same. They give different results. Which one is correct?

Comment: @ E.Z. If you see my code above, I did not use `clf.best_estimator_.score(X, y)`, but `clf.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)` because in the next step, I am making a confusion matrix. I want to find the average accuracy over the 10-fold with a standard error on the test data for the best parameter found by `gridsearchCV()`. How to do that?

Comment: Obviously, `score(X_train, y_train)` differs from `score(X_test, y_test)` because they are not similar vectors of values. As I have stated above, `score()` prints out the best metrics score while `cv_results_` prints out the averaged metrics score of batches. To answer the first question: your code is correct.

Comment: If you want to have the best metrics score for the test data, then you simply type `clf.best_estimator_.score(X_test, y_test)`, and the batching is obsolete. If you want to find the best averaged metrics score over the batches on your train data, then you pick the highest value of `mean_train_score` or `mean_test_score` stored in `cv_results_`. If you find it difficult to understand what `mean_test_score` and `mean_train_score` are you should read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratified-k-fold)

Comment: Go over carefully what I have written because this question is already answered above.

Comment: I got the answer to my 1st question. I understand that in my example above, `score(X_train, y_train)` and `score(X_test, y_test)` give the best metric scores for **train** and **test** data (i.e., with the best set of parameters  found using `gridsearchCV()`, right?), but my question is that if this score is cross-validated over the 10-fold on test data? I am interested average cross-validated score over the folds for the best set of grid parameters (not average score over the batches). It would be nice if we had one complete example written.

Comment: It is not cross-validated. In fact, it does not make any applicable sense. You should read more about cross-validation and why it is used. For example, it may be useful when a researcher does not have validation (test) data, so splitting training data into ten batches, 5 of which are for training and the other 5 for testing is a good idea. I recommend you simply grid over parameters without splitting your data as it will increase the score because the model has more data to be trained on. Or you may not utilize `train_test_split()` and use the whole set in `GridSearchCV()` with the `cv=10`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please finally provide an example code for this? I see that `gridsearchCV()` is using `cv=10` so there is some cross-validation.

Comment: Just do `clf.fit(Data, labels)` and leave everything else as it is. the `mean_test_score` in `cv_results_` will be the averaged test metrics you are looking for.

Comment: I accepted your answers. Thanks again. My initial understanding was that I could find the tuned (best set of) parameters using grid search, and with these tuned parameters, I could do 10-fold cross-validation to find the average accuracy over the folds on test data. Seems like that I can either find the best score with tuned parameters or I can find average accuracy over the fold, but not both together.